# loop through 2 google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, foreach, nested-loops

Goodday,

I have 2 sheets. For each ID on sheet1 I need to verify if that ID is also on sheet2 AND if Date Processed is blank.

If both condition are true > today's date should be set in Date Processed.

[image]

I've managed to do so for just 1 value (A2) from sheet1.
What I need is a way to go through all the values in sheet1. Ideally the row in sheet1 would also get deleted (not sure if that is possible)

This is my code till now

```
function myMatch(){
var file  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ss    = file.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var ws    = file.getSheetByName("Sheet2");

var wsData = ws.getDataRange().getValues();
var mySearch = ss.getRange("A2").getValue();

  for(var i = 0; i < wsData.length; i++){
    
    if(wsData[i][1] == mySearch && wsData[i][2] == "")
    {      
      ws.getRange(i+1,3).setNumberFormat('dd"-"mmm"-"yyyy').setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

Your help is really appreciated as I have been trying and searching for a solution for 2 days now. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it doesn't makes much sense. Muhammet's code works and looks just fine. But, rather for fun and educational purposes, here is another "functional" solution:

```
function myFunction() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const s1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const s2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');

  // get data from Sheet1 and Sheet2
  const s1_data = s1.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1,);
  const s2_data = s2.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1,);

  // get IDs from data of Sheet1
  const IDs = s1_data.map(x => x[0]); 
  const IDs_to_delete = []; // here will be IDs to delete

  // function checks and fill a row and adds ID to array to delete
  const write_date = (id,row) => {
    if (row[1] == id && row[2] == '') { 
      IDs_to_delete.push(id); 
      row[2] = new Date();
    }
  }

  // change rows within data of Sheet 2
  IDs.forEach(id => s2_data.forEach(row => row = write_date(id,row)));

  // clear and fill Sheet 2
  s2.getDataRange().offset(1,0).clearContent();
  s2.getRange(2,1,s2_data.length,s2_data[0].length).setValues(s2_data);

  // remove rows from data of Sheet 1
  const s1_data_new = s1_data.filter(row => !IDs_to_delete.includes(row[0]));

  // clear and fill Sheet 1 with new data
  s1.getDataRange().offset(1,0).clearContent();
  s1.getRange(2,1,s1_data_new.length,s1_data_new[0].length).setValues(s1_data_new);

}
```

The only improvements over Muhamed's code is that this implementation removes processed rows from Sheet1. And, I believe, it will work faster for huge lists, because it doesn't use `getRange()` and `setValue()` on every found cell but fills all cells of the sheet at once with `setValues()` method.

Comment: Thanks, what a great solution. Also for adding the explanation is really helpful. I needed some time to figure out what (x => x[0]) did but I understand now and I've tested it with a larger dataset. You are right, process time is very low (which is great). Again, thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

You need a loop for this. Use

> var mySearchs = ss.getRange('A2:A').getValues();

and loop through all values of this array.

```
function myMatch(){
  var file  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss    = file.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var ws    = file.getSheetByName("Sheet2");

  var wsData = ws.getDataRange().getValues();
  var mySearchs = ss.getRange('A2:A').getValues();

  mySearchs.forEach((v) => {
    for(var i = 0; i < wsData.length; i++){
      
      if(wsData[i][1] == v && wsData[i][2] == "")
      {      
        ws.getRange(i+1,3).setNumberFormat('dd"-"mmm"-"yyyy').setValue(new Date()); 
      }
    }
  })  
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Of course I should have used A2:A to loop through the whole column. I'm glad to see forEach in GS, I've only used it in VBA before. This works perfectly. But as Yuri pointed out I would better avoid using getRange on larger datasets. Anyhow, I've learned a good lesson and want to thank you for your time and response.